# greasemonkey throws SecurityError for a simple script

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm new to greasemonkey and trying to understand how greasemonkey is different from the embedded web console. A simple script which works perfectly on web console does **not** work on greasemonkey, and I have no idea why.

### Environments

- Firefox 74.0 on Arch Linux
- Greasemonkey 4.9

### Web Console

Here is the test script I use:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    const w = window.open('https://www.google.com/', 'w');

    console.log("Hello");

    w.onload = () => {
        console.log("World");
    };

})();
```

When I access https://www.google.com/webhp?gl=us&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&pws=0 (Google US top page), copy and paste the script into web console, and then execute it,

1. A new window `w` loading https://www.google.com/ is opened.
2. The string `Hello` is printed.
3. The string `World` is printed.

Everything is as expected.

### Greasemonkey

On greasemonkey, I use the script below. The header part is the only difference.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     test
// @namespace n
// @match https://www.google.com/webhp?gl=us&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&pws=0
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    "use strict";

    const w = window.open('https://www.google.com/', 'w');

    console.log("Hello");

    w.onload = () => {
        console.log("World");
    };

})();
```

When I access https://www.google.com/webhp?gl=us&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&pws=0 (Google US top page),

1. A new window `w` loading https://www.google.com/ is opened.
2. The string `Hello` is printed.
3. `SecurityError` is thrown saying

   > Script error in [Greasemonkey script n/test]:
   >   SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "onload" on cross-origin object test:42:19
   >       user-script:n/test:42

When I use `unsafeWindow` instead of `window`,

1. A new window `w` loading https://www.google.com/ is opened.
2. The string `Hello` is printed.
3. And nothing else happens. (No error, no `World`)

### Question

How should I modify the script so that is can be executed on greasemonkey?

---

**Update**

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903868/greasemonkey-throws-securityerror-for-a-simple-script#comment107752641_60903868), the script works on Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey under **Chrome**.

I haven't confirmed this but have confirmed that the script works on `Tampermonkey 4.10.6105` or `Violentmonkey 2.12.7` under **Firefox**.

Comment: This script is working in Chrome with Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey (both in page and content injection modes) and there's nothing that should prevent it from working despite what erosman claims. The security in the web is based on the same origin principle so the fact that Greasemonkey or Firefox throw an error means it's just a bug or an inherent deficiency of userscript API implementation.

Comment: @wOxxOm As you suggest, with `Tampermonkey 4.10.6105` on Firefox, the problem has completely been solved. But Tampermonkey is not OSS...

Comment: Well, use Violentmonkey then.

Comment: @wOxxOm I didn't know they [updated the privacy policy](https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey.github.io/commit/7964469da138b2c5db43d01d8f03820ac7cc5813). Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Console is part of browser scope while a GreaseMonkey script is injected into a page content and its scope it limited to that page only.

You can open a new tab/window from page content with GM but that window/tab will have its own page content scope which is separate from the first one. Therefore, you can not access properties belonging to another tab/window from a page content of different tab.

This separation is for all content scripts and not only for GM. Otherwise, it would have created a great security risk if JS in one tab/page could access data on other tabs.

**Update:**

As pointed out by wOxxOm, the CSP and cross-origin policy prevents [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

In your example, in Firefox, the first issue is that Firefox will "Block pop-up windows" from the content script.

Testing Firefox dedicated [userScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/userScripts) API on [FireMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemonkey/), after allowing popup, still causes an error:

> SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "onload" on
>   cross-origin object

In this case, I believe it is due to the sandboxing of userScripts for security.

GM/TM/VM do not use the userScripts API and use other means to inject userSripts which results in different outcome.